# Django 1.8 to 1.9 upgrade: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-1.8, django-1.9

I have a project currently working on Django 1.8. Since 1.9 just released, I thought I would update via `pip install django==1.9`. However, when running `python manage.py test -v 3`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from reversion.revisions import default_revision_manager, revision_context_manager, VersionAdapter
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 159, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/user/Envs/intranet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I am aware that INSTALLED_APPS changed from a tuple to a list.

Anything else that I might have missed?

Comment: You can run `manage.py check` to see what needs updating but thats assuming you can actually run manage.py

Comment: @Sayse: the same exception is raised.

Comment: Yeah I deleted my comment originally since I realised the issue is with running manage.py and not 1.9 but I added it back there as its useful for when it does work. Have you looked at any of the multiple duplicates of this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to upgrade django-reversion, today was released [1.10 version](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#110---02122015) with:

> Django 1.9 compatibility (@etianen).

message from discussion groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-reversion/3AQipnbKaUI

> The latest release of django-reversion (1.10.0) is now available on
>   GitHub and PyPi. This release adds compatibility with Django 1.9.
>
> Important: This release contains breaking changes. Please review the
>   release notes on GitHub before installing.
>
> These breaking changes were unfortunately required in order to support
>   Django 1.9. Happily, all you'll need to do is modify your reversion
>   import locations, and everything will continue to work.
>
> Happy coding!

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Sadly, I get another application throwning the same error (djanog-mass-edit) so I guess that upgrading will have to wait some more time.