# Django upgrading to 1.9 error "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

Tags: python, django

When upgraded to django 1.9 from 1.8 I got this error. I checked answers for similar questions, but I didn't think this is an issue with any 3rd party packages or apps.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/kishore/.virtualenvs/andone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/kishore/.virtualenvs/andone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/kishore/.virtualenvs/andone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
commands = get_commands()
File "/home/kishore/.virtualenvs/andone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/kishore/.virtualenvs/andone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
File "/home/kishore/.virtualenvs/andone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
self.check_apps_ready()
File "/home/kishore/.virtualenvs/andone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I'd modified the Installed apps for 'django.contrib.auth'.

Comment: are you using any third party app? Please share your settings.py

Comment: I'm using many 3rd party apps, but I believe this error is raised from "django/apps/registry.py" and not from any other apps in site packages.

Comment: I have faced a similar issue with django-crispy-forms because the ibrary doesnt support 1.9 yet. So this might be an unsupported app.

Comment: I'm not using that package. Sorry If I'm wrong, if it is related to any packages, the trace will be pointing to that app in site packages, right?

Comment: Same payu not support 1.9

Comment: I had the same issue. The problem was that in my console I run python and import models there instead of ./manage.py shell and then calling model

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'd a custom function written on one of my models `__init__.py` file. It was causing the error. When I moved this function from `__init__.py` it worked.

Comment: Same here, moving it fixed too.

Comment: Worth noting that commented out functions in this file may also cause this error.

Answer (score 176):

Try to add this lines to the top of your settings file:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

And if this will not help you try to remove third-party applications from your installed apps list one-by-one.

Comment: I tried it, but i got this error "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty." Even though I've the SECRET_KEY in settings file.

Comment: Try declaring the SECRET_KEY **BEFORE** the mentioned lines, something like:

SECRET_KEY = 'MY SECRET KEY'
import django
django.setup()

it worked for me.... now with another error :)

Comment: This is a great answer to question: "How do I access Django model objects from a stand alone script?" :-)  Before run the code above, you will need to do: os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your.settings") though.

Comment: Didn't work on settings but works on my standalone script.  This exception also happens if you forget to call django.setup() in a standalone Python script. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#troubleshooting

Comment: **`django.setup()` is for use in stand alone scripts. You shouldn't put it in settings**

Comment: To reiterate what @Alasdair has said, this is from the docs: `If you’re using components of Django “standalone” – for example, writing a Python script which loads some Django templates and renders them, or uses the ORM to fetch some data – there’s one more step you’ll need in addition to configuring settings.`

Comment: [django.setup in documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

Answer (score 54):

My problem was that I tried to import a Django model before calling `django.setup()`

This worked for me:

```
import django
django.setup()

from myapp.models import MyModel
```

The above script is in the project root folder.

Comment: I was facing this issue when running a script, this solved it.

Comment: If you're running a script, e.g. to access DB models, THIS IS IT!

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure to add `django.setup()` above all your import statements

Answer (score 18):

In my case, the error occurred when I made `python manage.py makemigrations` on `Django 2.0.6`.

The solution was to run `python manage.py runserver` and see the actual error (which was just a missing environment variable).

Answer (score 18):

The error occurs when you specify startup code that uses models.

If you follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) approach and put it into your `AppConfig` you **must not** import models at the top of the file, but inside the `ready()` method. For example as follows:

```
# works as models are imported in the ready() method
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MatcherConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'matcher'
    verbose_name = 'Match-Making'
    def ready(self):
        from matcher.background_tasks import close_timeout_games
        from matcher.models import FourPlayerGame
        # check if a player is not responding every 5 seconds
        close_timeout_games(FourPlayerGame, repeat=5)
```

However, the following would be **wrong**:

```
# won't work as models are imported at the beginning
from django.apps import AppConfig
from matcher.background_tasks import close_timeout_games
from matcher.models import FourPlayerGame

class MatcherConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'matcher'
    verbose_name = 'Match-Making'
    def ready(self):
        # check if a player is not responding every 5 seconds
        close_timeout_games(FourPlayerGame, repeat=5)
```

For more information also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055878/4858818) answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer for my case. Moving `imports` inside of `def ready(self)`  is what I needed.

Comment: This is the most correct, general and elegant answer. The other answers address specific instances of this, or usage in external scripts which is not OP's issue.

Comment: I hate deferring imports to local scope, but I found Django already does this. I spent two frustrating hours trying every other solution and wishing I had already built CI/CD to test for this type of failure. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

This error may occur when you are adding an app in `INSTALLED_APPS`  in the `settings.py` file but you do not have that app installed in your computer. You have two solution:

1. `Install` that app using package managers like `pip` in ubuntu
2. Or Comment out that installed app in the `settings.py` file

This error may also arise if you are not in your `virtual environment` which you may have created for your project.

Answer (score 10):

---

***First import and run django.setup() before importing any models***

---

All the above answers are good but there is a simple mistake a person could do is that (In fact in my case it was).

I imported Django model from my app before calling `django.setup()`. so proper way is to do...

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()
```

then any other import like

```
from faker import Faker
import random
# import models only after calling django.setup()
from first_app.models import Webpage, Topic, AccessRecord
```

Answer (score 7):

For me, the problem came from the fact that I was importing an app in `INSTALLED_APPS` which was itself importing a model in its `__init__.py` file

I had :

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myapp',
    ...
]
```

`myapp.__init__.py`

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
```

commenting out `import models` in `myapp.__init__.py` made it work :

```
# from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
```

Comment: I have the similar problem. But I need the import in my case. How would you do that?

Comment: You can always refactor to avoid importing models from __init__. An option that would work for sure would be to refactor the files importing your app but it might be quite heavy changes. In the end, it's what I had to do!

Comment: Same issue as @JohnnyQ. Works fine in 1.8 but breaks in 1.9. 
Is there any relevant documentation somewhere around? 
The exception arises due to import of User from django.contrib.auth.models in my case

Comment: Had asked about this in a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927122/django-upgrade-from-1-8-to-1-9-is-breaking-on-model-import-in-init and got the answer.
Gist, no other way but to refactor

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the entire `settings.LOGGING` dictConfig and restart the server. If that works, rewrite the setting according to the v1.9 documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/#examples

Comment: Thanks it worked. For me I was using setting files of linux on windows. Hence `/var/log` logfile path dint exist which gave this error

Answer (score 5):

You may get this error if you've started normal Python shell by mistake and trying to import your Django models in that.

You should instead use `python manage.py shell` for that.

Answer (score 3):

For me commenting out

```
'grappelli.dashboard',
'grappelli',
```

in INSTALLED_APPS worked

Comment: For me it was just that I accidentally had `'one_third_pary_app,'` instead of `'one_third_pary_app',` (note the position of the `,`)

Answer (score 3):

django.setup() in the top will not work while you are running a script explicitly.
My problem solved when I added this in the bottom of the settings file

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
import sys
if BASE_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] =  "igp_lrpe.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "igp_lrpe.settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: I use Pycharm shell and type
`import django`
and
`django.setup()`. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

I put the `User` import into the `settings` file for managing the rest call token like this

```
# settings.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler(payload):
   ....

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER': jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': PUBLIC_KEY,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': API_IDENTIFIER,
    'JWT_ISSUER': JWT_ISSUER,
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Because at that moment, Django libs are not ready yet. Therefore, I put the `import` inside the function and it started to work. The function needs to be called after the server is started

Answer (score 2):

I get that error when I try to run `test.py`(not full scripts, I don't want to use `python manage.py test`)

and the following method is working for me.

```
import os
import django
if 'env setting':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'YourRoot.settings')
    django.setup()
from django.test import TestCase
...

class SomeTest(TestCase):
    def test_one(self):  # <-- Now, I can run this function by PyCharm
        ...

    def test_two(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Assuming `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is defined, there are 2 important lines of code in this answer; `import django` and `django.setup()`.

If one is using objects from a django project in a one-off python script *within* the project, the scope of that script most likely doesn't have access to the django project. By calling the aforementioned lines, you essentially let that script know about the contents of your django project. When I need to call these, I just add them to the top of the script before any other imports.

Comment: `if 'env setting'` seems useless.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was:
django-reversion>=1.8.7,<1.9

for django 1.9.7 you should use:
django-reversion==1.10.0

I were upgraded django-cms 3.2 to 3.3, and found it by commenting apps, then uncommenting back.

Correct answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34040556/2837890

Answer (score 1):

This issue is also observed for inconsistent settings.py for incorrectly writing INSTALLED_APPS, verify if you correctly included apps and separated with "," .

Answer (score 1):

When I change my django version to 1.9, it don't arise the error.

`pip uninstall django
pip install django==1.9`

Answer (score 1):

I was in trouble with such matter
my problem was because of having this piece of code in settings.py

import myapp.models

when I removed this code problem fixed
I recommend check your settings.py and remove such code

Answer (score 0):

In my case one of my settings, 'CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST' was set in the settings.py file but was not available in my .env file. So I'll suggest that you check your settings, especially those linked to .env

Answer (score 0):

As others have said this can be caused when you've not installed an app that is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

In my case, `manage.py` was attempting to log the exception, which led to an attempt to render it which failed due to the app not being initialized yet. By 
commenting out the `except` clause in `manage.py` the exception was displayed without special rendering, avoiding the confusing error.

```
# Temporarily commenting out the log statement.
#try:
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
#except Exception as e:
#    log.error('Admin Command Error: %s', ' '.join(sys.argv), exc_info=sys.exc_info())
#    raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried tons of things, but only downgrading Django to 1.8.18 fixed this issue for me:

```
pip install django==1.8.18
```

It is one of the installed apps that is failing, but I could not find which one.

Answer (score 0):

I get that error when i try to run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

i tried so many things and realized that i added some references to "settings.py" - "INSTALLED_APPS"

Just be sure what you write there is correct. My mistake was ".model." instead of ".app."

Corrected that mistake and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

For others that might stumble upon this in future:

If you encounter this issue while running Python 3.8 and trying to use multiprocessing package, chances are that it is due to the sub processed are 'spawned' instead of 'forked'. This is a change with Python 3.8 on Mac OS where the default process start method is changed from 'fork' to 'spawn'.
This is a [known issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31169) with Django.

To get around it:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
mp.set_start_method('fork')
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when I was trying to load a function in the init file (`__init__.py`) of my settings package.

The cause of this error

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet
```

is that, before settings were loaded, I wanted to load another module (e.g. `rest_framework`).

To solve this, I put functions in another module (file) in settings package
(e.g. `common.py`), and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I got this error `appregistrynotready` is That I accidentally  **Register** `User model` in `app.py` instead of `admin.py`

This is how it's looked like

`app.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: The issue here is not that you *registered* it, but that you **imported** it. The import is executed when the file is read, and app.py is read before django has setup its models and apps (admin.py is not, that's why it works there)

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue when i used

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

Solution:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party, but grappelli was the reason for my error as well. I looked up the compatible version on pypi and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try activating the virtual env.
In my case, using the git command line tool:

```
source scripts/activate
```

Solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Got this error while trying to access model objects in `apps.py`:

```
class QuizConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'quiz'

def ready(self):
    print('===============> Django just started....')
    questions_by_category = Question.objects.filter(category=2) # <=== Guilty line of code.
```

Trying to access `Question` before the app has loaded the model class caused the error for me.

Comment: Does the model `Question` defined in the models.py of this AppConfig?

Comment: Yes, it is defined there

Answer (score -1):

I've run into this problem and it was rooted in asgi.py. we've loaded the below module:

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
```

but we didn't use it in the ProtocolTypeRouter. apparently, we have to use
websocket or other protocols when we call the AuthMiddlewareStack module.

Answer (score -2):

In the "admin" module of your app package, do register all the databases created in "models" module of the package.

Suppose you have a database class defined in "models" module as:

```
class myDb1(models.Model):
    someField= models.Charfiled(max_length=100)
```

so you must register this in the admin module as:

```
from .models import myDb1
admin.site.register(myDb1)
```

I hope this resolve the error.

Answer (score -3):

If your setting.py files fill are correct，you can try to arrive manage.py files proceed call danjgo.setup() in main method . Then run manage.py ,finally again run project ,the issue could disappear.