# Django: Cannot create User inside ipython shell

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, ipython, python-3.4

I am trying to import Django User model in ipython inside virtual environment. I have tried the following code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

It resulted in the following error

```
AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Then from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115677/6619424), I have setup inside the shell and tried the following code.

```
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
```

This resulted in `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects' .` How can I create a user inside ipython shell? I am using Django 1.10.6, 
 ipython 6.0.0 and djangorestframework 3.6.2

Comment: Try only this: User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')  -> this works for me. I would suggest you to user "shell_plus"

Comment: Well, AUTH_USER_MODEL is a string. Why are you doing this? If you start your shell via `manage.py shell` you can import User as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by starting the ipython shell using the command

```
python manage.py shell -i ipython
```

Answer (score 2):

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a string, inside shell you can import User as model from django.

For this, run `python manage.py shell`

Or you could manually import django and set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

For that, inside ipython run these,

```
import django, os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'testproject.settings'
django.setup()
```

Then you can do,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

then you can create users inside shell like this,

```
User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
```

Comment: I cannot import User model, It shows the error: AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: yes, I did. I can import user model inside shell. The problem happens when I run this inside ipython.

Comment: what's your django version?

Comment: It's Django 1.10