# Ubuntu 16.04 Server error about wsgi module in wsgi.py

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, server, mod-wsgi

I'm gonna set a django app on a ubuntu server in a virtual host.
I have configured my virtual host so that something comes up!
But it persists on giving me 500 internal error because of some issues as you see here:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=31972): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mmcba/mmemp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=31972): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mmcba/mmemp/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/mmcba/mmemp/wsgi.py", line 25, in <module>
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I really appreciate your responses

---

**Update #2**

if I use this code in my wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

stack trace will become this:(`mmemp` is my app's name):

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=5579): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mmcba/mmemp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=5579): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mmcba/mmemp/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/mmcba/mmemp/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named mmemp.settings
```

My Virtual Host Config., Here it is:

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost 148.251.218.202:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mmcba.com
        ServerName mmcba.com
        ServerAlias www.mmcba.com

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mmcba/mmemp/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/mmcba/mmemp>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Which version of django are you using?

Comment: Django 1.10 using Python 3.5.2

Comment: Show the mod_wsgi configuration you are using. It doesn't look like you have told mod_wsgi where you project is located.

Comment: I've added my virtual host configuration and also updated my stack trace --after reversing some mistakes. it's nearly a new error. Would you please take a look at the second stack trace again. & thank you for your response

Comment: You should use daemon mode of mod_wsgi, not embedded mode. You then aren't telling mod_wsgi where your project code is located as per the Django documentation. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: It still gives me same errors :(

Comment: Update the configuration in your question to show what you are using now.

Comment: Got it. I added project and app dirs to sys.path and finally it found settings module. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
  Add project and App dir to sys.path in wsgi.py and it'll work.
It works for every unknown module in your app

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<Project_Directory>')
sys.path.append('<Project_Directory>/AppName')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using django 1.7+ do replace contents of your `wsgi.py` with this:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

OR try adding the following lines to `settings.py`

```
import django
django.setup()
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you but it's not working I've inserted new stack trace at the bottom of my question

Comment: Is the project working in your local machine? Also please check whether there is `__init__.py` file inside your app directory (mmemp)

Comment: Of course, it's working like a charm! yeah there is one :(

Comment: You should not place wsgi.py in your app folder, instead put it in project folder.