# Where in Django can I run startup code that requires models?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, startup

On Django startup I need to run some code that requires access to the database. I prefer to do this via models.

Here's what I currently have in `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from .models import KnowledgeBase

class Pqawv1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'pqawV1'

    def ready(self):
        to_load = KnowledgeBase.objects.order_by('-timestamp').first()
        # Here should go the file loading code
```

However, this gives the following exception:

`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

So is there a place in Django to run some startup code after the models are initialized?

Comment: Move the `from .models import KnowledgeBase` *inside* the `def ready` method. Here importing it in the header results in the fact that the models are loaded too early.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, this works, thanks. But how good is this solution? What are the side effects? I'm quite new to Python...

Comment: the difference is that you simply only import `.models` when the config calls `ready`, you thus postpone importing. It was due to "eager" importing that this resulted in trouble.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you import `.models` at the top of your file. This means that, when the file `app.py` file is loaded, Python will load the `models.py` file when it evalutes that line. But that is *too* early. You should let Django do the loading properly.

You can move the import in the `def ready(self)` method, such that the `models.py` file is imported when `ready()` is called by the Django framework, like:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class Pqawv1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'pqawV1'

    def ready(self):
        from .models import KnowledgeBase
        to_load = KnowledgeBase.objects.order_by('-timestamp').first()
        # Here should go the file loading code
```

Comment: Once the data or resources is loaded in `ready()`, how could we use them in `views`? Import appconfig?

Comment: @advocado: you can obtain the appconfig for a given app with `from django.apps import apps`; `apps.get_app_config('app_name')`. If you store your resorce that is loaded on the `self` (so `self.to_load = ...`), you thus can access it with `apps.get_app_config('app_name').to_load`. But you should do that in a function, since the models are loaded *before* the `ready` function is triggered.

Comment: Great (and also concise) answer!

Comment: As an aside, `from .models import *` will fail ("SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level") while `from .models import KnowledgeBase` will succeed

Comment: This is [explicitly discouraged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) by the docs. The reason is if you run tests, the `ready()` code will still run against your production database, not the test database.  See [discussion here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22002).