# Django database-dependent one-time initialization

Tags: python, django

In my Django app, I have a `routing.py` helper module with a `get_route` function that is used by my app. Before I can call this function, I need to build a graph network, which is slow (seconds), so I want to do this once instead of on every `get_route` call. I build my graph network based on data in my database, so I need to access models (read-only) during this initialization. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055815/where-in-django-can-i-run-startup-code-that-requires-models) is similar but as pointed out there, the accepted answer is wrong, since it relies on django's AppConfig.ready(), but as is pointed out in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready), if you make database queries in there, they will access your production database instead of your test database when running tests. Is there a way to do one-time initialization after Django has loaded the database?