# django exception: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a website using django, pycham and python.
While trying to run the code I got this error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Akriti/Documents/santulitahar/santulitahar/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Akriti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Akriti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Akriti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Akriti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "C:\Users\Akriti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Akriti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet

Comment: I added an edit that might make it easier to read. The question could be further improved by providing some of the surrounding code and some things you've already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django upgrading to 1.9 error "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet)