# Django 1.9 Upgrade Issue "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

Tags: python, django

I upgraded from `Django 1.8` to `1.9` but facing this problem

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

None of the other solutions on stackoverflow worked.

I already tried other solution like adding

```
import django
django.setup()
```

but no success.

```
File "/home/adithya/git/django_proj/manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
  File "/home/adithya/git/virtualenv/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 83, in <module>
    class Site(models.Model):
  File "/home/adithya/git/virtualenv/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/adithya/git/virtualenv/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/adithya/git/virtualenv/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Could you add the full error stacktrace?

Comment: Have you look at the answers in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet) ?

Comment: Attached the full error tracelog

Comment: Can you show your `./manage.py` file? Why are you importing site in it?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, so I will leave the answer )

There are a lot of ways to get this error actually, you just need to find it. I left some popular variants below, but the real cause in your case may be different.

Check:

1. Any custom functions in models **init**.py files - they may be the cause
2. Also, consider that Django requires django.setup() to be run before parts of an app can be called. During the setup phase, one important thing that it does is apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS). If you try to access an app before setup has run the function check_apps_ready will raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
3. This exception may occur due to a misconfiguration of wsgi file

Also, you can try to disable your apps in INSTALLED_APPS one by one, maybe that will identify where the problem is coming from?

Comment: It was working fine in Django 1.8 but when i migrated to Django 1.9 this issue started.

Comment: Also i have commented out entire Installed Apps but still the issue persists.

Comment: Are all your packages support 1.9?
And again - make sure you're not importing models or anything else from your app's __init__.py files

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed by removing depricated code in **manage.py**.
Also i was using old s3 storage (boto3 apps) which was incompatible with new Django Versions.
Fixing those two issues solved my problem.