# Issue with Django: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

Any idea what's causing this error? I've tried commenting out each app in INSTALLED_APPS one by one to see which one isn't loading, but I get the same error no matter which one is commented out. It happens after I call django.setup(), and I'm trying to create a REST API.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/main.py", line 18, in 
         django.setup()
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
         apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
         app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
         module = import_module(entry)
       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
         return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
       File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
       File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
       File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
       File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
       File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
       File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
       File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
       File "", line 728, in exec_module
       File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in 
         from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in 
         class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 107, in __new__
         app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
         self.check_apps_ready()
       File "/Users/ColeHoward/PycharmProjects/Face_Recognition_App/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
         raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
     django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Have you seen the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet)

Comment: I did, none of those solutions worked for me