# Not able to run the coverage with pytest-cov and pytest

Tags: django, pytest, code-coverage, django-testing, pytest-cov

Facing issues in running the pytest with coverage, I have gone through the SO posts and not able to fix this, I believe I'm missing something here..

Getting the following errors where users is an app of my project

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

My pytest.ini file contents

> [pytest]  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = cloudstack.settings
> python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_test.py
> addopts = -v --ignore=venv --cov=. --cov-report=html

I have tried adding DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as environment variable too then I'm getting different error saying that `cloudstack module is not found`.

I'm in the activated environment while performing these tests.

**EDIT**
I looked into every post of the stack overflow to fix the errors in running the pytest with coverage none of them helped me in resolving this.

[Django upgrading to 1.9 error "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet)

[PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)

[ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set)

And I had everything aligned as per the instructions in the SO posts'

> $ type -a coverage coverage is
> /cygdrive/c/#Work#/Python/Django/Projects/cloudstacko/cvenv/bin/coverage

> $ type -a pytest pytest is
> /cygdrive/c/#Work#/Python/Django/Projects/cloudstacko/cvenv/bin/pytest

> $ type -a python python is
> /cygdrive/c/#Work#/Python/Django/Projects/cloudstacko/cvenv/bin/python
>
> sys.path
> ['/cygdrive/c/#Work#/Python/Django/Projects/cloudstacko/cloudstacko', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/cygdrive/c/#Work#/Python/Django/Projects/cloudstacko/cvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library which saved my day.

> $ pip install pytest-django