# Is there a way to use reverse outside of a Django App?

Tags: python, django

Long story short, I need to call a python script from a Celery worker using subprocess. This script interacts with a REST API. I would like to avoid hard-coding the URLs and django reverse seems like a nice way to do that.

Is there a way to use reverse outside of Django while avoiding the following error?

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I would prefer something with low-overhead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet does this answer your question

Comment: @luederm,  Maybe you can use `reverse_lazy `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

> If you’re using components of Django “standalone” – for example,
> writing a Python script which loads some Django templates and renders
> them, or uses the ORM to fetch some data – there’s one more step
> you’ll need in addition to configuring settings.
>
> After you’ve either set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or called `configure()`,
> you’ll need to call `django.setup()` to load your settings and populate
> Django’s application registry.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a custom manager command to boot my django app from external scripts. It is like smashing a screw with a hammer, but the setup is fast and it takes care for pretty much everything.