# 502 occurs when creating environment on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having an issue deploying my first Django project.

Here's my `config.yml`:

```
global:
  application_name: testapp
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: us-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: Application
```

And here's my `django.config`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: djangoproject.wsgi:application
```

I have followed [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html). But after I did `eb create testapp-env`, I get 502 error:
[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDD6L.png)

I will provide further information if you need. Thank you in advance for your help.

Here's the error in `web.stdout.log`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

**UPDATE**

My django project uses python-socketio, and here's my wsgi.py:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import socketio
from post.socketioserver import sio # <- it's just my socket io code

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangoproject.settings')

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, django_app)
```

I get another error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Open your elastic beanstalk environment in the AWS console, then requests the logs, so you can obtain more info.

Comment: Which log file should I see? There are a lot of log files...

Comment: I can see in `web.stdout.log` errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable:

```py
option_settings:
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
      WSGIPath: djangoproject.wsgi:application
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "djangoproject.settings"
```

Also you need to edit your `wsgi.py` file because you are accessing an app before Django setup:

```py
import django
django.setup()

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import socketio
from post.socketioserver import sio # <- it's just my socket io code

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangoproject.settings')

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, django_app)
```

Comment: @robust-person After you changed the `wsgi.py` file restart the server. After the restart you still see the same error in `web.stdout.log`?

Comment: It seems like my wsgi.py and yours is pretty the same. Is there any flaws I made?

Comment: @robust-person I have updated my answer (also restart the server)

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. I'll update my question to include the error message.

Comment: @robust-person This is a different error (we have resolved the first). Probably you are getting the new error because you write `from post.socketioserver import sio` before Django setup. I have updated my answer. If after you have restarted the server you still get the error, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet).